# .vcf data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, vcf-variant-call-format

How can I convert [this VCF data](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/26dc2b5679668d02d04d71895539ff9f) into a pandas dataframe?

<sup>Note: The full file is not needed to replicate the problem. Just the first 50 lines (first part of gist link above) will do.</sup>

Ideally I would like it in the form:

[image]

Thus far I have only been able to get the headers:

```
import pandas as pd

f = open('clinvar_final.txt',"r")

for line in f.readlines():
    if line[:5] == 'CHROM':
        vcf_header = line.strip().split('\t')

df = pd.DataFrame
df.header = vcf_header
```

Comment: this question is very vague. what should the dataframe look like? should all of the information from your file be present? how do you want the columns to be organized? and lastly, have you tried anything yet? if so, what was it and how did it not meet your needs?

Comment: Edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: Your file is not in proper VCF4.1 format. The first header should be `#CHROM` not `CHROM`.

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey I edited the post to point to a gist containing both a 50-line snippet and the full original file to avoid link rot. I changed the full file to have the `#`, but not the snippet. Unfortunately, both the OP's code and the highest-voted answer depend on it's not being there. This makes the question/answer not very portable.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to read line by line.

Pandas has an option called `comment` which can be used to skip unwanted lines.

You can directly load VCF files into pandas by running the following line.

```
In [9]: pd.read_csv('clinvar_final.txt', sep="\t", comment='#')
Out[9]: 
        CHROM        POS      ID REF ALT FILTER QUAL                                               INFO
0           1    1014O42  475283   G   A      .    .  AF_ESP=0.00546;AF_EXAC=0.00165;AF_TGP=0.00619;...
1           1    1O14122  542074   C   T      .    .  AF_ESP=0.00015;AF_EXAC=0.00010;ALLELEID=514926...
2           1    1014143  183381   C   T      .    .  ALLELEID=181485;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C4015293,OMIM:...
3           1    1014179  542075   C   T      .    .  ALLELEID=514896;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C4015293,OMIM:...
4           1    1014217  475278   C   T      .    .  AF_ESP=0.00515;AF_EXAC=0.00831;AF_TGP=0.00339;...
...       ...        ...     ...  ..  ..    ...  ...                                                ...
102316      3  179210507  403908   A   G      .    .  ALLELEID=393412;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C0018553,Orpha...
102317      3  179210511  526648   T   C      .    .  ALLELEID=519163;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C0018553,Orpha...
102318      3  179210515  526640   A   C      .    .  AF_EXAC=0.00002;ALLELEID=519178;CLNDISDB=MedGe...
102319      3  179210516  246681   A   G      .    .  AF_EXAC=0.00001;ALLELEID=245287;CLNDISDB=MedGe...
102320      3  179210538  259958   A   T      .    .  AF_EXAC=0.00001;ALLELEID=251013;CLNDISDB=MedGe...
```

Comment: Please note that, unlike the OP's data, a valid VCF file will have the line beginning with `CHROM` prepended with a `#` character (see [Erik McKelvey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219758/vcf-data-to-pandas-dataframe#comment124215934_70219758) above). This means that either the headers will need to be specified manually in the call to `pd.load_csv()`, or the file will need to be parsed to find that line.

Answer (score 1):

GATK Variantstotable is what you need to avoid any issue due to the flexibility of the format of the VCF. Then, when having the csv, import it into pandas. I would say that this is the most robust way to do this.

https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360036896892-VariantsToTable

Comment: This is actually the most correct answer here at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Simple function:

```py
import io
import os
import pandas as pd


def read_vcf(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines = [l for l in f if not l.startswith('##')]
    return pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(''.join(lines)),
        dtype={'#CHROM': str, 'POS': int, 'ID': str, 'REF': str, 'ALT': str,
               'QUAL': str, 'FILTER': str, 'INFO': str},
        sep='\t'
    ).rename(columns={'#CHROM': 'CHROM'})
```

Takes a VCF file, removes the metadata lines, and converts the remaining data into a Pandas DataFrame, with specific column data types and renaming applied.

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    chrom_index = [i for i, line in enumerate(lines) if line.strip().startswith("#CHROM")]
    data = lines[chrom_index[0]:]  
    header = data[0].strip().split("\t")
    informations = [d.strip().split("\t") for d in data[1:]]

vcf = pd.DataFrame(informations, columns=header)
```

Comment: I would recommend you to add some explanation to your code above.